# Vapor-Liquid Equilibrium and partial pressure of ammonia

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, solubility, vapor-pressure, gas-phase-chemistry

I tried searching the forums for a similar question but I do not think it was entirely answered:

Suppose I have a closed system in a container with solvent and a certain concentration of gas, say ammonia ($C_{NH3}$), in the liquid phase at a fixed temperature which is at equilibrium (assuming all ideal gases for now). The gas phase will have a pressure based on the individual partial pressures of the components in the headspace, where each individual partial pressure can be expressed as the mol fraction multiplied by the total pressure (for ideal gases):

$P_t$ = $P_1$ + $P_2$ + $P_3$...

$P_i$=$x_i$*$P_t$

**Question 1:** If the desire is to increase the concentration of ammonia (${NH}_3$) in the liquid phase at a fixed temperature, would adding more nitrogen gas ($N_2$) into the gas phase help with this to increase the overall pressure of the vapor space above the liquid ? My initial thoughts here are to apply Henry's law where the solubility of a gas in a liquid is proportional to its partial pressure (at a certain temperature): $S=k*P$, [Henry's Law link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Solutions_and_Mixtures/Ideal_Solutions/Dissolving_Gases_In_Liquids%2C_Henry%27s_Law), but I am not clear as to what happens to the partial pressure of ammonia in this example (total pressure increases, but mol fraction of ${NH}_3$ decreases)

**Question 2:** Will the liquid concentration of ammonia, $C_{NH3}$, be affected by changes in the gas-phase volume at a fixed liquid volume and temperature (i.e. keep the same liquid volume in larger and larger closed containers). My initial thought here is, as the gas-phase volume (or headspace volume) increases, more moles of the components will move from the liquid to the gas phase to achieve the same equilibrium pressure at a fixed temperature, but not entirely clear here.

Thanks for the help and let me know if I can provide more clarity to the questions. Relatively new to this forum as well

Comment: Ammonia is very bad example, unless it is explicitly your case. It's extreme solibility significantly and not very linearly  modifies properties of initial water solvent.

Comment: Increased total pressure would  cause slight increase of chemical potential of dissolved gas, what would lead to slightly higher gas partial pressure with the same dissolved gas concentration.

Comment: @Poutnik, so you are saying then increasing total pressure would not significantly change the partial pressure of ammonia in the gas phase